# Add Images to windows form so they work after publish

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2013

I am currently setting my images in my windows form like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\Krum\\11.jpg");
```

But this will not work after I publish the product and load it from another computer at another location.

How do I add images to my project so that they will work after I publish and send it to another computer? What path do I use and where do I need to add them?

**UPDATE**:

Trying to find the path to my file after adding it to properties is not working very well. In my prperties the file looks like this:

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap one {
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("one", resourceCulture);
            return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
        }
    }
```

And then I try to use it like this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
        thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        System.IO.Stream file =
            thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.one");
        this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the image file to the project, and set the Build Action property to Embedded Resource in Solution Explorer and then use something like:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = 
    thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.ImageFile.jpg");
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287676(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I tried running the code for finding the name of the resources in my assembly and it gave me this: "WFA1.Form1.resources" and "WFA1.Properties.Resources.resources" ... How do I find the path I want to add as a parameter for `GetManifestResourceStream()` ? Sorry but I am completely new to this

Comment: no problem, I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for here in your latest comment. If the following article doesn't help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287526(v=vs.71).aspx Then maybe you could create a new question on SO.

Comment: Yeah thats the article I read and used. But just gives me "Stream cant be set to null" error even when I think I found the right path =/ Ill try updating my question here and maybe ur spider senses can see what Im doing wrong, haha

Comment: `*EDIT* I just added this comment before I saw your previous one.` The string parameter passed in to `GetManifestResourceStream(...)` Should be something like `thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsFormsApplication1.Penguins.jpg");` Where WindowsFormsApplication is the name of your project/namespace. I think you should create a new question on SO as you may get better answers as the question is different from the original title now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to embed the images in the assembly file, you could always add them to your solution, set the property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Always", then use the following code to acces relative paths:

```
var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var filename = Path.Combine(directory, "Images", "Image1.png");
```

Additionally, if you are using a setup project, also include the folder/files to install along with the assembly.