# xDocument.Load(sTemplatesDir + "Config.xml") wont execute on published application

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have an Excel Add-in which imports and reads multiple xml documents. This works while Debugging in Visual studio. However once published the load command will not execute but also will not throw an error.

I assume the issue is a access rights based one.

The command is:
xDocument.Load(sTemplatesDir + "Config.xml")

```
public string sTemplatesDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Templates\\";
```

Following the installation the directory exists:

> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\BVMP5DJA.R9P\D4WCZN4V.BVN\irob..vsto_85867b9a9100fe99_0001.0006_59cceacced2231ac\Data\Templates

for my instance

Comment: Your path seems odd. There are 2 dots `..` in it. Or is this just an abreviation?

Comment: @tom Is there any update in this issue？ Do you have time to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Update: According to the OP feedback, this problem is caused by the wrong file address, just copy the file to the correct address to run.

Tom:

> The issue seems to be the folder "Templates" upon install. It copies is located in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\W93YRNR1.WM7\Z87VQ6P2.VVY\irob...dll_85867b9a9100fe99_0001.0006_done50b02 However I need it to be located : C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\W93YRNR1.WM7\Z87VQ6P2.VVY\irob..vsto_85867b9a9100fe99_0001.0006_5cc74931dfbb886c (Copying it here makes) the app

For file copying, you can use [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) in msbuild.

Comment: Unfortunately it isnt a rights issue. The issue seems to be were the folder "Templates" upon install. It copies is located in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\W93YRNR1.WM7\Z87VQ6P2.VVY\irob...dll_85867b9a9100fe99_0001.0006_none_2201d50bc60ea937                                     However I need it to be located : C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\W93YRNR1.WM7\Z87VQ6P2.VVY\irob..vsto_85867b9a9100fe99_0001.0006_5cc74931dfbb886c (Copying it here makes the app work)

Comment: How would I identify this directory with xCopy. this only occurs once published. If I can located the directory to copy from I can just reference that in my app instead?

Comment: For xcopy, you can directly find the address of the original file that needs to be copied, and then copy it to the required address.

Comment: Regarding your problem, I think you may have a problem with your file publishing settings. Normally we refer to the file https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895678/16764901 like this, we can easily find the file we need, whether it is embedded or copied directly. If you are struggling with your current job, you can try the ones I mentioned. You can also try the resource file.

Comment: My publish setting for all the files in the folder "Templates" are set to "copy always" and are deployed to "Application files" folder when published. I think xCopy is the solution however What would be the location for the copy target. This will change dynamically per install?